# C++ call static function of class in main

Tags: c++, function, class, object, static

I have a class

```
class Triedenie_cisla{
    public:
        Triedenie_cisla(int *poleHodnot, int ddlzka); 
        int *pole, dlzka;
        double bubble_cas, selection_cas, insertion_cas, quick_cas;
        vector<int> mnozina_int;                   
        string vypis_pola();        
        void BubbleSort_int();      
        void SelectionSort_int();   
        void InsertSort_int();  
        void QuickSort_int();
        void static zorad_Sorty();
};
```

And the function

```
void Triedenie_cisla::zorad_Sorty(){
    if ( (quick_cas<bubble_cas) && (quick_cas<selection_cas) && (quick_cas<insertion_cas) ) {
        cout << "The best one is Quick Sort with time "<< quick_cas << " ms"<< endl;
    }
}
```

And in my main.cpp I need to call this function. **Triedenie_cisla::zorad_Sorty();**
I used static thkinking that may help calling me function without creating object, but I always get these errors

> error C2597: illegal reference to non-static member
>   'Triedenie_cisla::bubble_cas'
>
> error C3867: 'Triedenie_cisla::bubble_cas': function call missing
>   argument list; use '&Triedenie_cisla::bubble_cas' to create a pointer
>   to member

How to solve the problem ? Thanks much, I am quite new at c++

Comment: It looks like the class offers sorting functionality, but also records timings of those sorts. That seems like poor design, if I understand correctly. You should not mix up sorting and timing into one class. Have a class for sorting. Perform the timings separately.

Answer (score 3):

Since `zorad_Sorty` is static, it can only access static members. But your implementation accesses non-static members.

If you need to access non-static members of this class, you will have to instantiate an instance of it.

Alternatively, if you must use a static method, you will have to implement that method using only static members.

Answer (score 0):

As the error says you cannot use non-static members in a static function.
You could gradually make everything you need to use static, but as it probably makes more sense just to create the object in main, and use it.
e.g.

(**edit**) If you had a default constructor...

```
//...

Triedenie_cisla object;

object.zorad_Sorty();
```

Otherwise provide the parameters it needs:

```
Triedenie_cisla object(&poleHodnot, ddlzka);

object.zorad_Sorty();
```

Comment: I was trying to do it like this howerver when I try to create object I get this type of error.
 'Triedenie_cisla' : no appropriate default constructor available

Any idea how to deal with this ? Thanks

Comment: @user3292179 The compiler is right. You did not provide a default constructor.

Comment: But I have no idea how to provide deafualt constructor, I neednt use it in my progam except here.

Comment: Provide a default constructor only if it makes sense to do so. Otherwise use the constructor that you did provide, the one that takes two parameters.